# RSpec: Shared examples for Validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have several models that have `start_time` and `end_time` and I have a custom validator that has special rules for these fields. For testing, I feel like I've got 3 options:

1. Have a **validator and validator_spec**. Then **re-test the entire implementation** of the validators in every model to ensure that the validator is working with that model.
2. Have a **validator and validator_spec**. In each model, somehow check that the already-tested validator is being included in a model. (Maybe this means testing one condition that would only arise from the validator being included.)
3. Creating a **shared example** as the validator test, and include it in each model's test (although `it_behaves_like SomeValidator` looks kind of weird)

Any thoughts? The validator has several conditions so I'd find it taxes and not DRY to implement #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would propose another option:

4.) implement a validator_spec and build a custom matcher which can be reused in every model using this validator

maybe you can find some inspiration at https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Answer (score 0):

The 'mockist' approach would be to write a spec for the validator class, so that it can be tested in isolation. Then in your model specs, you can stub the validator to return a pre-determined value.

**There is a trade-off here:** You're avoiding a combinatory increase in the number of tests, so your test suite will smaller, faster, and easier to maintain. But your introducing a small risk that in some situations a model may not work in combination with the real validator once integrated in the production code.